# How to initialize repeating tasks using Django Background Tasks?

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, background-task

I'm working on a django application which reads csv file from dropbox, parse data and store it in database. For this purpose I need background task which checks if the file is modified or changed(updated) and then updates database.
I've tried '**Celery**' but failed to configure it with django. Then I find **django-background-tasks** which is quite simpler than celery to configure.
My question here is how to initialize repeating tasks?
It is described in [documentation](http://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#repeating-tasks)
but I'm unable to find any example which explains how to use **repeat**, **repeat_until** or other constants mentioned in documentation. 
can anyone explain the following with examples please?

```
notify_user(user.id, repeat=<number of seconds>, repeat_until=<datetime or None>)
```

> repeat is given in seconds. The following constants are provided:
>   Task.NEVER (default), Task.HOURLY, Task.DAILY, Task.WEEKLY,
>   Task.EVERY_2_WEEKS, Task.EVERY_4_WEEKS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to call the particular function (`notify_user()`) when you really need to execute it.
Suppose you need to execute the task while a request comes to the server, then it would be like this,

```
@background(schedule=60)
def get_csv(creds):
    #read csv from drop box with credentials, "creds"
    #then update the DB

def myview(request):
    # do something with my view
    get_csv(creds, repeat=100)
    return SomeHttpResponse
```

Excecution Procedure
1. Request comes to the url hence it would dispatch to the corresponding view, here `myview()`
2. Excetes the line `get_csv(creds, repeat=100)` and then creates a `async task` in DB (it wont excetute the function now)
3. Returning the HTTP response to the user.
After 60 seconds from the time which the task creation, `get_csv(creds)` will excecutes repeatedly in every `100 seconds`

Comment: get_csv(creds, repeat=100) is not working. repeat is an unexpected argument in function. @Jerin

Comment: I don't think so, because It's worked for me well. Can you add your all related code ?

Comment: call the `get_csv(creds, repeat=100)` function from **Django Shell**. If you still got the `unexpected argument` error, it means you missing something in your code

Comment: My bad, actually I'm using Visual Studio Code and it was raising unexpected argument error, but when I tried `python manage.py process_tasks` it worked.
Thank you. @Jerin

Answer (score 2):

For example, suppose you have the function from the documentation

```
@background(schedule=60)
def notify_user(user_id):
    # lookup user by id and send them a message
    user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    user.email_user('Here is a notification', 'You have been notified')
```

Suppose you want to *repeat* this task **daily** until **New Years day of 2019** you would do the following

```
import datetime
new_years_2019 = datetime.datetime(2019, 01, 01)
notify_user(some_id, repeat=task.DAILY, repeat_until=new_years_2019)
```

Comment: There are unexpected arguments repeat and repeat_until in notify_user(some_id, repeat=task.DAILY, repeat_until=new_years_2019). Where should I call notify_user? @sytech

Comment: Hmm. Are you sure that you added the decorator to the function? I just tested this and it works fine for me.

Comment: It worked. Problem was in visual studio code. Thank you. But `repeat=Task.DAILY` is not working. Only number args are accepted. Why so? @sytech